# Is space $F(x, y) = \{ g(x) + h(y) : g, h \in C[0, 1]\}$ closed in $C([0, 1]^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

How to show that
$$F = \left \{ g(x) + h(y) : g, h \in C[0, 1] \right \} = C[0, 1]+C[0, 1]$$
closed in $C([0, 1]^2)$  where norm is given by $\| f \| = \sup_{0\le x , y \le 1} |f(x,y)|$. How should I approach it?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + Please [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: As context, in MSE chat on April 11 (e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63349125#63349125) it was observed that it is sometimes true that the algebraic sum $V+W$ of closed subspaces of a normed space is itself closed - for example, if the normed space is a Hilbert space and $V$ and $W$ are orthogonal (or perhaps more generally if the orthocomplements of $V \cap W$ in $V$ and $W$ are respectively orthogonal). That this general observation does not apply here (e.g. because $C[0,1]^2$ with this norm is not a Hilbert space) would be useful context to add to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: for $(a,b) \in [0,1]^2$, let $E_{a,b}$ denote the (bounded) linear functional on $C[0,1]^2$ given by evaluation at $(a,b)$.  See if you can show that
$$
S = \bigcap \{\ker(E_{a,b}+E_{0,0}−E_{a,0}−E_{0,b}): (a,b) \in [0,1]^2\}
$$

Comment: If anyone is interested in context surrounding this problem, OP raised it on the MSE chat at the same time as posting here.  There, "attempts" were made, including a variant where $C[0,1]$ was replaced with $L^2[0,1]$, and generalizations involving other sums of closed subspaces of normed spaces were considered